# Gif keeps overlapping in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

So, my gif is completly fine in photoshop and is showing it is perfect and good to go. But when I see it on the web, this is what happens. I am trying to make it transparent.

[http://i.imgur.com/n0SzRYV.gif](https://i.imgur.com/n0SzRYV.gif)

I cannot fix this and I am really in need of some help. Any ideas? Or can someone fix this for me?

Comment: Do you need the background to be transparent?

Comment: @Jongware Yes, I am trying to get the background to be transparent aswell.

Answer (score 13):

Select all frames, then right-click (control-click) and choose `Dispose`.

If frame disposal is disabled, one frame just overlays the next so any frames underneath will still be visible through any transparent areas on the frame above.

With frame disposal set, each frame disappears before the next one plays.

Comment: What will this accomplish? Adding more detail will make your answer a whole lot better

Comment: I had to use `Export` > `Save for Web (Legacy)` for this to work. The regular `Save as` did not respect the `Dispose` setting, for some reason.